# Android 12 and 13 not get onesignal push notification even after upgrade onesignal package to 4

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal, android-13

java android application does not receive a notification on android 12 and 13 when I use the package `'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.2'`  now after upgrading the package to `com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]`  I still do not receive a notification. Can anyone help me find a solution to my problem?